# Not possible to open partial view in jquery dialogue despite examples to the contrary

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

So despite many examples and answers on Stack Overflow, I've found it impossible to open an MVC partial view as a jquery dialogue.  The dialogue opens up but the content is always empty.  It seems the .load() function is completely ignored.  Here's my code, would appreciate any input.  This is probably something simple, as always.

**I have a DIV in the main body of my form:**

[image]

I have a button and a script that respond to the button click, and opens a dialogue.  Here is that code:

[image: **enter image description here**]

When I click the button, I always get an empty dialogue, **as shown here**:

[image]

**My partial view looks like the following**.  No matter what goes into this partial view, it is never shown.  I've tried other partial views and checked the names carefully, but they're never displayed:

[image]

The culprit seems to be the .load() function.  No matter what I put into it, the dialogue remains empty.  I can put complete garbage in the controller or action name of the Url.Action and/or replace the Url.Action with a hardcoded pathname that doesn't exist but the code doesn't blow up, I still get the empty dialogue:

[image]

Any and all thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Your question needs to include the code, not images of it. And note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first `load()` the contents of the dialog and *then* open it.

Something like:

```
$('#AttachmentDialogue').load('@Url.Action(...)', function() {
    $(this).dialog('open');
});
```

(You'll have to omit your current `load()` in your `open` callback as well)

Comment: Nice suggestion.  I gave that a try, but the load() call still seems to be the culprit.  I am debugging the jquery code in Visual Studio and looking at the innerHtml of the div AFTER the load() call and it is still an empty string :-(

Comment: @markaaronky, Make sure your server actually receives the request and does serve HTML in response.

Comment: Found the problem Haim, thank you, please see answer below.  The load() was failing silently.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer to this one.  If you have your Action method in your controller decorated with [HttPost], and do not have a method to handle [HttpGet], load() will **silently fail** and return empty HTML.

I had, in my haste, decorated the Action method with the wrong attribute, POST instead GET.   What's odd is that if you type the URL in the address box of IE, you'd get what you would expect: a "page not found" error, when you don't have a method to handle the GET that results from the load().  However, when trying to load the same page (well, partial view) from jquery, you get no error--just silence.

So, below, if the **second** Action exists in the controller, a load() for a partial view of "_AttachmentViewer" will succeed.  If it isn't there, the load() fails silently and the dialogue box remains empty.  The GET/POST makes sense and was my mistake; the silent failure surprises me.

[image]